# Powershell prompt freezes

Tags: command-line, powershell, freeze

On several boxes with Windows 10 or 11, the PowerShell command prompt regularly freezes For several seconds during a session, at times 30 seconds or more.

The keyword buffer works ok, but after hitting enter, the freeze occurs. After the delay, the contents of the keyboard buffer is mostly processed.

On the win 11 box, it may have occurred after installing the MS Graph and/or Azure Modules. Another box in a  heavily managed and secured win 10 environment where additional modules are neither installed nor loaded shows thesame behaviour. This renders Powershell nearly useless.

What may be the cause, and more
Important, how to cure it?

Comment: Do you happen to use OneDrive and synced your My Documents and desktop etc with it? That will slow down Powershell by a lot. Also MSGraph is very heavy and will slow down auto complete. Its likely a mixture of both.

Comment: Both may apply for the Win 11 box but not for the win 10 box.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're doing, which commands you type (feel free to hide confidential data with bogus data, as long as the commands remain in tact)?

Comment: It doesn’t actually matter which, even “show-command” or get-childitem for the current directory hangs.

Comment: I may add, when using PowerShellISE, the execute functions are partly grayed-out. It seems that PowerShell (definitely on the Win 11 box) is doing some activity in the background blocking anything else

Comment: Use ProcessExplorer to watch the PowerShell process while hang occurs.

Comment: Are you 100% sure there's no OneDrive sync going on on these Win 10 boxes? Maybe another form of sync or backup? It really sounds like a filelock. Maybe virus scanner?

Comment: There „Home“-Drive is synched with a fileserver on the win10-box also. So that may be at least part of the problem.

Comment: @music2myear: ProcessExplorer is only available on the Win 11 Box. What should I watch out for there?

Comment: @LPChip: If the syncing is causing a file-lock, can this be neutralized in some way? Even if I‘m getting used to inconsistent an incoherent behavior (if not erratic) development directions by Microsoft 365  lately, I can’t imagine that OneDrive and PowerShell are intended to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: In my case, the powershell profile resides in my My Documents folder (that's default), and that was placed in OneDrive (because I got a prompt, do you want to make a backup of your files?). When powershell is active, it writes lots of small changes to many files (mostly modules) in that path, and OneDrive then wants to sync this to the cloud, which prevents Powershell from changing those files and it has to wait for the sync to complete. When I turned off sync, the problem went away instantly.

Comment: But its really simple. On a computer you have access to, check if OneDrive is running there, and if so, close the OneDrive client, then test if the program goes away immediately. If so, problem found.

Comment: @LPChip: Turning off OneDrive sync seems to solve the freeze. So it at least makes PowerShell usable again. Thanks so far! I will test this over the following days. But this cannot be the real solution - two of the most central ms-tools  should be able to coexist.

Comment: The problem really is that powershell has so much disk activity that any sync solution just doesn't work well with it. I agree that it should, but there are lots of things that should but aren't.

Comment: ProcessExplorer runs on all Windows versions. Your question does not reference any other systems, and ProcExp will work on all the OSes you note and should be used.